# Although one ore more error occured, contract execution completed

Tags: solidity, internal-transactions

The following transaction was sent from what seems to be a Parity multisig wallet:

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xf244329caaee10dd1378ff744a569f37a8dc8dd606921233deccb51e0ed0c5a0#internal

The receiving contract throws when the default entry point is called. My understanding is that the transfer failed, but that etherscan displays that execution completed because the error is captured.

In this respect, the 25 ethers sent as part of this transaction must have never left the original contract. However, the sender of this transaction insists that their balance decreased by 25 ethers, which seems impossible.

Am I missing something? Is this a behavior I'm not aware of, a bug in Solidity, or is the sender mistaken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That transaction executes the proposal `a2614b9ce2589b917f712d0e696b37f1f890af12ca260f538977c4c4b0eec001`. That proposal was created at tx [0xb97f048e343d75c9e3df85b98295725c4abff8c72a39a796af6fab906a58118c](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xb97f048e343d75c9e3df85b98295725c4abff8c72a39a796af6fab906a58118c).

Decoding the transaction you have

- `_to`: 0xb56d622ddf60ec532b5f43b4ff9b0e7b1ff92db3 ([TezosCrowdsale](https://etherscan.io/address/0xb56d622ddf60ec532b5f43b4ff9b0e7b1ff92db3#code))
- `_value`: 0x15af1d78b58c40000 (25 ether)
- `_data`: [] (empty array!)

When the proposal is confirmed the multisig wallet will execute:

```
_to.call.value(_value)(_data);
```

Since `_data` field is empty it will call the fallback function for the TezosCrowdsale, and it will throw an exception immediately.

```
  /* no default action, in case people forget to send their data
     or in case they use a buggy app that forgets to send the data */
  function () {
    throw;
  }
```

In this case it works as the funds never left the multisigwallet. To ensure this is correct you have to check the balance of the multisig wallet `0x99C04a7ad876e7afc2B1182CeA8804ae253317bb` before and after block `3957178` which contains transaction `0xf244329caaee10dd1378ff744a569f37a8dc8dd606921233deccb51e0ed0c5a0`.